# How to drag and drop between 2 DevExpress GridViews?

Tags: winforms, drag-and-drop, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-gridcontrol

I'm using DevExpress 19.2, .NET Framework 4.6.1, C#, Visual Studio 2017, WinForms.  I want to move data from one DevExpress grid to another.  I've been unable to find a complete example online, but have cobbled together data from multiple sources.  Unfortunately, I can't quite get it right.  Can someone explain what I'm missing or point me to a working example?

My first attempts come based on info from this link: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/118656/common-features/behaviors/drag-and-drop-behavior#how-to-customize-drag-and-drop-operations.  It works, but I have to hard code the name of the GridControl in the code.  This works as a proof-of-concept, but eventually, I'll have multiple grids and I'll need to find what GridControl it's for.  The DragDropEventsArgs have the GridView data, but I haven't been able to find the GridControl data.

Here's how it looks after I drag the data from one grid to another:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
private void dragDropEvents2_DragDrop(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.DragDrop.DragDropEventArgs e)
    {
        DragDropEvents dde = (DragDropEvents)sender;
        BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dde.Container.Components[0];
        CustomerWorkOrderViewModel wo = (CustomerWorkOrderViewModel)bs.Current;

        //GridView target = (GridView)e.Target;
        GridView target = (GridView)e.Target;

        BindingSource bsTarget = (BindingSource)target.DataSource;
        SortableBindingList<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel> sblTarget =
            (SortableBindingList<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel>)bsTarget.DataSource;
        List<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel> listWo = sblTarget.ToList();
        if (listWo == null)
        {
            listWo = new List<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel>();
        }

        if (listWo.Where(x => x.customerWorkOrderID == wo.customerWorkOrderID).Count() == 0)
        {
            listWo.Add(wo);
            gridControl2.DataSource = listWo;
            gridControl2.RefreshDataSource();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The part I need to change is hard coding GridControl name in the code:
[image]

The second attempt I found is from this link: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.Utils.DragDrop.DragDropEvents.DragDrop.  It's not quite right because it's from a TreeView to a GridView, but I've been able to change the TreeView part.  The part that doesn't work is adding data to the new grid.  The example shows adding a new row to the grid and then getting the handle.  However, when I use the code to get the handle, it gives me a negative value.  I tried hard coding the row handle as 0, but it give me a mismatch of blank data and the data I want to add:

[image]

Here's the code example:

```
private void dragDropEvents1_DragDrop(object sender, DragDropEventArgs e) {
List<TreeListNode> list = e.Data as List<TreeListNode>;
foreach (TreeListNode node in list) {
    gridView1.AddNewRow();
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["DEPARTMENT"], node.GetValue(colDEPARTMENT1));
}
    e.Handled = true;
 }
```

Here's the code for this version:

```
private void dragDropEvents2_DragDrop(object sender, DevExpress.Utils.DragDrop.DragDropEventArgs e)
    {
        DragDropEvents dde = (DragDropEvents)sender;
        BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dde.Container.Components[0];
        CustomerWorkOrderViewModel wo = (CustomerWorkOrderViewModel)bs.Current;

        GridView target = (GridView)e.Target;

        BindingSource bsTarget = (BindingSource)target.DataSource;
        SortableBindingList<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel> sblTarget =
            (SortableBindingList<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel>)bsTarget.DataSource;
        List<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel> listWo = sblTarget.ToList();
        if (listWo == null)
        {
            listWo = new List<CustomerWorkOrderViewModel>();
        }

        if (listWo.Where(x => x.customerWorkOrderID == wo.customerWorkOrderID).Count() == 0)
        {
            target.AddNewRow();
            target.SetRowCellValue(0, target.Columns[0], wo.customerWorkOrderID);
            gridControl2.RefreshDataSource();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: The GridView object exposed in the DragDrop event handler (e.Target) has a GridControl property. You can simply use (e.Target as GridView).GridControl.RefreshDataSource(), or something along those lines :)